# How do I split runs of alpha characters and numeric characters in a string?

Tags: javascript, arrays, split

I have a array that looks something like this:

```
var things = ["33bn", "2x", "Apple123"];
```

How can I convert that array into this:

```
var things = ["33", "bn", "2", "x", "Apple", "123"];
```

Would it be possible to do this with split and RegExp?

I'm not sure as to how I should do this, maybe I could loop through the array and split each item using RegExp then push each item of the new array into the old one?

Comment: Yes. What did you tried?

Comment: @Roque I must admit, I am slightly lost when it comes to doing this... Maybe I should loop through the array and split each item using RegExp then push each item of the new array into the old one?

Comment: Are the string and numbers always grouped together like in your examples, or could they be mixed like "123abc456"?

Comment: @skyline3000 Most are mixed but there are one or two that aren't.

Comment: As a follow-up then in the example I gave, are you expecting 3 items "123" "abc" "456" or "123456" "abc"? And will any items be only characters or numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `.reduce` like this:

```
var things = ["33bn", "2x", "Apple123"];

things.reduce(function(item, i){
  return item.concat(i.match(/\d+|[A-Za-z]+/g));
}, []);
```

Comment: And why not `return res.concat...`?

Comment: @torazaburo Cool!..extra optimized

Comment: Thanks for the simplest & easiest to understand answer, its safe to use with older browsers and can be easily to poly-filled. Works like a charm and it solved my problem thanks, I appreciate it +1.

Answer (score 8):

With [arrow-function ready browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=arrow-functions):

```
things.map(t => t.match(/\d+|[A-Za-z]+/g))
    .reduce((x, y) => x.concat(y));
```

```js
var things = ["33bn", "2x", "Apple123"];

var result = things.map(t => t.match(/\d+|[A-Za-z]+/g))
  .reduce((x, y) => x.concat(y));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Good solution. Warning about support though. [Only 55% of current browsers support arrow functions](http://caniuse.com/#feat=arrow-functions).

Comment: Notably few mobile browsers support arrow functions

Comment: @Roque There is no need for such disclaimers, any more than one needs a disclaimer for `forEach`. If you are running code in an environment that doesn't support arrow functions, then rewrite them as regular functions. If you don't know how to do that, then learn, and learn quickly.

Comment: @torazaburo Well as the support is still very limited, I do think it is important to point it out. OP may not be aware of this limitation.

Comment: @Roque No, it's not important to point it out. It's a waste of time, space, and mental bandwidth. If he is not aware of it, he will run into it soon enough.  Do you plan to go through all of SO and add disclaimers to every answer that uses arrow functions?

Comment: @torazaburo I don't agree.

Comment: @Roque See [related discussion on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326630/should-answers-include-support-requirements?noredirect=1#comment360055_326630).

Comment: @torazaburo Thank you for asking the question on meta.

Answer (score 3):

Spread operator, arrow functions:

```
var result = [].concat(...things.map(a => a.match(/\d+|[a-z]+/gi)));
```

Comment: Lest someone obsessed with support for ES6 features, or lack thereof, in their favorite browser think that this elegant solution is limited to ES6, note that it could easily be written as `[].concat.apply(0, things.map(function(a) { return a.match(regexp); }))`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `forEach` loop and append the items with spread operator `...` to a new list.

```js
var things = ["33bn", "2x", "Apple123"],
    other = [];
things.forEach(el=>other.push(...el.match(/\d+|[a-z]+/gi)));
console.log(other);
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be my solution

```js
var things = ["33bn", "2x", "Apple123"];
things = things.reduce((p,c) => p.concat(c.match(/\d+|[a-z]+/ig)),[]);
console.log(things);
```